# How to run multiple scripts in turn?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 5 scripts that you want to run with one click, Can anyone advise me what to do? Each script sets a new line position, which is why I want each script to be a space and only now has the ending run until the last one.

```
function CreateNewRows() {

  if(check > 2){
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(141, 48)
    sheet.getRange('B112:U125').copyTo(sheet.getRange('B150'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS, false)
    sheet.getRange('B112:U125').copyTo(sheet.getRange('B165'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS, false)
    sheet.getRange('B112:U125').copyTo(sheet.getRange('B180'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NO_BORDERS, false)  }
}

function CreateRacecard1() {
  if (checkRM >0) {    
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(match1, checkRM)
    sheet.getRange(adressCopyRM).copyTo(sheet.getRange(adressPasteRM), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL)
  }   
}

function CreateRacecard2() {
  if (checkU >0) {    
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(match2, checkU)
    sheet.getRange(adressCopyU).copyTo(sheet.getRange(adressPasteU), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL)  
  }
}

function CreateRacecard3() {
  if (checkS >0) {    
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(match3, checkS)
    sheet.getRange(adressCopyS).copyTo(sheet.getRange(adressPasteS), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL) 
  }
}

function CreateNewRows1() {
    if (howAR >0) {    
    sheet.insertRowsBefore(match4, howAR)
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the function `CreateRacecard1` ever be called from more than one source?  Is there a reason why you aren't putting all of the code into one function?

Comment: Just put all five functions into another function

Answer (score 1):

Just place all your functions into a single function (or all the code into a single function).

```
function doAllThings() {
  CreateNewRows();
  CreateRacecard1();
  CreateRacecard2();
  CreateRacecard3();
  CreateNewRows1();
}
```

## Adding delay between the functions

You can add delay between calls by using the [`Utilities.sleep`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleep(Integer)) method.

## Create a macro button

You can either [create a new Menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) to run your function or bind a [macro do a clickable shape](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this way before and run all scripts at the same time.

Comment: Wasn't that what you asked for? Please explain more clearly so we can help.

Comment: When I run each script manually, it loads everything correctly. Now I would like to use one button to run all the scripts in sequence. It is important that they operate in the order I set. Running the script you proposed causes the effect of running all at once. Is it possible to set the interval between scripts 5 seconds? Maybe this way I will achieve the goal.

Comment: @AphaGeron I have update my answer to reflect what you told me. Please try to add this information to your original question when possible.